# No insulation behind duct work, basement wall

Tags: insulation, ducts

Insulating my basement with 1.5" thick XPS foam to achieve R-7.5.  Great. All things happy. Except I ran into an issue.

My rectangle ducting (the main trunk) line actually stops a 1/4" away from my concrete wall.  A simple oversight I / HVAC guy made.  There was no insulation on the wall during install, so the idea wasn't in mind.  But now here I am insulating this wall all over with foam, and BAM, a void with no foam.

And, of course this void is at the top of the basement wall, where the outside is exposed to nature, meaning the most heat loss/gain at this point of the wall.

Obviously I can't insulate behind it.  Should I just leave an inch of air gap all around the ducting?  That's my best idea.  It's not an area I can insulate, and it's not worth tearing out the ducting to shorten the trunk.  It's just a little nerve racking after being so attentive to insulating the wall and now I have this hole, more or less.

Comment: I'm unclear on how big an area we're talking about here -- is this the end of a trunk, or the entire length of a run is against the wall? A picture might help.

Comment: @gregmac This is just the end of the trunk.  Roughly 24" x 10" rectangle.  I'm thinking I should just leave it alone and not foam around the ducting.  This will allow any condensation to breath and dry versus staying wet and not drying out due to the air-tight seal next to my insulation.